# Codeigniter activerecord query continuously runs

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, mysqli-multi-query

When I try to run the follow query it never returns anything, it just keeps running. What am I doing wrong with it?

```
$this->db->distinct('customer.Name')
                    ->from('customer')
                    ->from('invoicelinedetail')
                    ->from('invoice')
                    ->from('iteminventory')
                    ->where('invoice.CustomerRef_ListID = customer.ListID')
                    ->where('invoicelinedetail.IDKEY = invoice.TxnID')
                    ->where('invoicelinedetail.ItemRef_ListID =', $id)
                    ->order_by('customer.Name', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: I don't think `distinct()` takes any parameters.  I think you need to do: `->distinct()->select('customer.Name')`.  I'm also unsure if you can call `->from()` multiple times, try `->from('customer, invoicelinedetail, ...')` or use `->join()`.  I could be 100% wrong, though.

Comment: Also, what does "t just keeps running" mean?  Do you mean the page never loads in your browser?

Comment: a model method mut return something aswell :) try using return on the query to see that it returns an object. use @Dan's answer below to to extract what you want.

Comment: I'm actually getting inconsistent data with models somehow. I'm trying it a different way now though.

Rocket Hazmat: Exactly. The page never loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `$this->db->get();` you need to retrieve your results

[More info from CI Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

To do this, set `$query=` to one of the following:

```
$this->db->result_array(); //returns array
$this->db->row_array(); //returns single row as array

$this->db->result(); //returns object
$this->db->row(); //returns single row as object
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot ASAP. Thanks, Dan!